# JPA EclipseLink oracle db missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I have a criteriaQuery:

```
CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type"), 1));
```

Then build rowCount query from the existing query:

```
   CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
   Root<Employee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
   Predicate restriction = criteriaQuery.getRestriction();
   if (restriction != null)
      countQuery.where(restriction);

   countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(root));
```

From debugging,

```
Predicate restriction = criteriaQuery.getRestriction();
```

criteriaQuery.where is (TYPE = ?), seen from debugger.
the restriction above returned is not (TYPE = ?), but ((TYPE = ?) = ?).

Eclipse generated SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ((TYPE = ?) = ?)
```

that causes error on oracle 11g db.

```
 Error Code: 907
    Call: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ((TYPE = ?) = ?)
            bind => [1, true]
    Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Employee.class sql="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ((TYPE = ?) = ?)")
00:31:24,718 ERROR [system] ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1991)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllReportQueryRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2675)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1793)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1775)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1740)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
```

what is the reason for generating ((TYPE = ?) = ?) instead of (TYPE = ?).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am using EclipseLink 2.5.1 on Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the actual value of "TYPE" being bound, it seems that embedded single quotes within the actual value being bound may be causing this error.

A quote from the following site explains this: [ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00907_missing_right_parenthesis.htm)

> If you are using single quotes in phrases that are surrounded by other single quotes, you have to add another single quote by the inner single quotes to avoid ORA-00907.  For example, you have to use '***''***''***' instead of  '***'***'***' in order for ORA-00907 to not be thrown over syntax.

*EDIT 1

Consider also looking at static metamodel representations of your typed parameters. For example:

```
ParameterExpression<String> typeParam = criteriaBuilder.parameter( Integer.class );

criteriaQuery.where( criteriaBuilder.equal( root.get( Employee_.type ), typeParam ) );
```

Where Employee_ type is a static metamodel as defined by the JPA spec.

Here is an example of this using an older version of EclipseLink. YMMV:

[JPA 2.0 Criteria API with Maven and EclipseLink](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2010/05/28/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-with-maven-and-eclipselink/)

Comment: Updated the question, and found the issue. Have not figured out how to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to strip away the ((TYPE = 1) = true) to become (TYPE = 1),  or prevent (TYPE=1) from being wrapped as  ((TYPE = 1) = true)?

Comment: Can you post your Employee entity? Not sure if how it is annotated is affecting how the SQL is generated internally.

Comment: Please see my edit above. This is given you are able to make such changes to your code base which leverage this.

Comment: To answer your previous question, I do not know of a way to strip away the generated SQL fragment unless you were to do something like extend the AbstractQuery.getRestriction method and perform some post processing there. Not sure if that is the best way forward. Try playing with the suggestion above using ParameterExpression.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am trying to row count the query results of any CriteriaQuery. That is why I need to copy over the restriction to countQuery. AbstractQuery.getRestriction() changes the restriction, not original one, which causes error for oracle db. The employee entity is just an example. Do not know why EclipseLink want to change the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse predicates/restrictions between the queries as they are tied to a specific CriteriaBuilder which is tied to a specific query.  EclipseLink does allow reusing a built query, but you have to access native API and clone the underlying EclipseLink query before making changes.

Comment: I like to stay away from native API. if adding a dummy 1=1, i.e., (TYPE = ?) and (1=1), it works. Is there a way to tell if a restriction is an conjunction(AND) of at least two boolean expressions? If false, add dummy (1=1).

Comment: Does the original query work if you don't try to execute the count query?

Comment: original query works. but building query incrementally using criteriaQuery.getRestriction() and adding new predicates will fail

Comment: As mentioned, the value returned from getRestriction cannot be reused in other queries, as it is tied to the original query.  It is not supported by EclipseLink as it causes the native expressions objects to be shared when they need to be cloned or better yet rebuilt from the new query.

Comment: Thanks. but JPA provides getRestriction() method, and the result should be usable. The wrapper ((a=b)=true) is wrong, because some databases do not like the syntax.

Comment: The results are usable, just not in the way you are trying to use them, which is not supported in JPA.  I was wrong and EclipseLink would support this, but it isn't working due to a bug.  See http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/Dynamically-get-a-Count-for-any-CriteriaQuery-is-it-possible-td6317.html for James' take on it - the getPredicate is wrapping the expression with a isTrue clause which causes a problem on your count query when only a single boolean expression is used.